# Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 3.50 — which point am I missing?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The problem :

[image]

In the hint of problem 3.50 it is mentioned that k-th elementary function defined as follows $$S_k (x)=\sum_{1\leq i_1 <i_2\cdots < i_k\leq n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_n} $$ is concave. Since we know that logrithim of a positive concave function is concave therefore $S_k (x) $ is concave. But $S_2 (x)=xy $ and $\log (xy) $ is convex. Which point am I missing here? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the book. Post the whole question so those who don't can try to help you.

Comment: I thought $\log (xy)$ was concave.

Comment: @kimchilover maybe i am wrong in finding the Hessian but i do not see where. The determinant of the hessian is $1/(x^2y^2) $ which i think is positive. Right?

Comment: The determinant of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ is positive, but the function $f(x,y)=-(x^2+y^2)/2$ is not convex.

Comment: @SeanRoberson The book is available on the internet  http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf. He's talking about page 123

Comment: as @kimchilover is saying $\log$ is concave.

Comment: @RHowe the fact remains I shouldn't have to do extra work to determine the question context.

Comment: @SeanRoberson that is true. However, it is like one of the most cited books in the history of the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand the right hand side in the link, you can show that 
\begin{equation}
 a_{k}(\lambda) 
 =
 \sum_{1 \leq j_1 \leq \ldots \leq j_k \leq n}
 (-\lambda_{j_1})(-\lambda_{j_2}) \ldots (-\lambda_{j_k})
 \qquad
 1 \leq k \leq n
\end{equation}
or simply
\begin{equation}
 a_{k}(\lambda) 
 =
 (-1)^k
 \sum_{1 \leq j_1 \leq \ldots \leq j_k \leq n}
 \lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} \ldots \lambda_{j_k}
 \qquad
 1 \leq k \leq n
\end{equation}
You can prove that $(a_{k}(\lambda))^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is concave on $-R_{+}^n$ because each of the $\lambda$'s are positive. Now since  $(a_{k}(\lambda))^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is concave on $-R_{+}^n$, then its log is log-concave.